# .Net Core 2.0 difference between PostgreSQL Date Coming from Query

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've a trouble about Datetime field and PostgreqSQL . 
I'm running a query at Postgresql .

This is the date result of query .

```
2018-08-30 15:17:42.091847-04
```

But when I debuged the application side . I've a different date .Shown as below.

```
 30.08.2018 05:52:47
```

This is the my service side convertion code. My model is fine but at the service side date is not same as the database .

```
 machineCreateDate= row.IfDbNullGetDefault<DateTime>("machineCreateDate"),
```

How I can handle this  problem .
Best Regards.

Comment: have you got a different timezone set in each place perhaps? I notice it's the same day but a different time.

Comment: It would be an odd time zone to be 9 hours, 35 minutes and 5 seconds different... Hmm.

Comment: @ADyson the first one is the true datetime in my own database . I think the problem is at dotnetcore timezone .

Comment: Hm. The problem may well be in .NET Core, but whether it's a timezone issue I don't know. On reflection Jon makes a valid point - what timezone would it be, exactly? Timezones are normally an exact number of minutes different. And usually on the hour or half hour. The 35 minutes and 5 seconds makes a timezone issue seem less likely, unless you've implemented some strange custom timezone. When I commented I hadn't calculated the exact time difference.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your help